# iFrame Width Locked After Rotation on iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, web, landscape-portrait

I have an iFrame within a website, which has `width=100%` (http://utjeha.me/multi-media/webcam-wetter.html) which works fine so far.

Now, when I rotate the iPhone to landscape mode, the iFrame adapts the new width just fine.

However, when I rotate the iPhone back to protrait mode, the iFrame stays in the old width, and does NOT adapt the width anymore.

How can this be fixed?

PS: This problem does occur in iPhone with Safari/Chrome. But NOT on an Android device.

[image]